# Can we categorify the equation (1 - t)(1 + t + t^2 + ...) = 1?

Tags: homological-algebra, categorification

Polynomials in $\mathbb Z[t]$ are categorified by considering Euler characteristics of complexes of finite-dimensional graded vector spaces.  Now, given a rational function that has a power series expansion with integer coefficients, it seems natural to consider complexes of (locally finite-dimensional) graded vector spaces.

Are there nice examples of this in nature?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the Euler characteristic of a complex of finite-dimensional graded vector spaces?  I just need to make sure I know where t comes from.

Comment: @Qiaochu. The graded dimension of a graded vector space V=\oplus_i V_i is dim_t(V) = \sum_i t^i dim(V_i). The graded Euler characteristic of a complex of graded vector spaces is just the alternating sum of the graded dimensions of the terms of the complex.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, the particular equation you wrote is categorified by the free resolution of k as module over k[x] by the complex $k[x] \overset{x}\longrightarrow k[x]$ given  by multiplication by x.  It also appears in the numerical criterion for Koszulity of k[x] (see the paper of [Beilinson, Ginzburg and Soergel](http://mathaware.org/jams/1996-9-02/S0894-0347-96-00192-0/S0894-0347-96-00192-0.pdf)).

Answer (score 13):

I think the following does what you want:

Let R be a polynomial ring in one variable x over a field with its usual grading; i.e. x has degree $1$. Next consider the graded complex that is R in degree $0$ and $R[1]$ in degree $-1$ --- here by R[1] we mean 
 $R[1]_ i=R_{i-1}$, and with the non-trivial map given by multiplication by $x$.

I guess that you would understand the Euler characteristic of this complex to be

$$(1-t)(1+t+t^2+t^3+...)$$since you might consider the "graded dimension" of the degree 0 part to be $1+t+t^2+...$ and the "graded dimension" of the degree $-1$ part to be $(t+t^2+...)$.

However when you take homology you get $0$ in degree $-1$ and just $k$ in degree $0$ and this $k$ has "graded dimension" $1$.

You do get things like this in nature when you try to compute Euler characteristics of $p$-torsion modules for Iwasawa algebras: see [K0 and the dimension filtration for $p$-torsion Iwasawa modules](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Esjw47/rankskzero.pdf) (by Konstantin Ardakov and Simon Wadsley, DOI: [10.1112/plms/pdm053](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/pdm053)) for some more calculations in this context. The notion of graded Brauer character there replaces the simpler notion of graded dimension.

Comment: Aaah. To slow. That's what comes from writing at length...

Answer (score 7):

I don't know whether or not this satisfies the criterion of "categorification" (what that?), but the equation (1 - t)(1 + t + t<sup>2</sup> + ...) = 1 and its relation to vector spaces is well-known to differential topologists and geometers.  We use it all the time in K-theory and index theory where it becomes the identity Λ<sub>-1</sub>V ⊗ S<sub>1</sub>V = ℂ.  Here, Λ<sub>-1</sub>V denotes the alternating sum of the exterior powers of V whilst S<sub>1</sub>V is the sum of the symmetric powers.

Of course, the sum of the symmetric powers isn't a class in K-theory as it is an infinite sum.  To get round this, we work in K[[t]] and allow parameters, whereupon the equation becomes Λ<sub>-t</sub>V ⊗ S<sub>t</sub>V = ℂ.  Here, the t means formally multiply the kth exterior or symmetric power by t<sup>k</sup>.

Where this breaks out of mere formalism and becomes very powerful is in equivariant K-theory.  Then the parameter becomes a way of measuring the action of the group, which is usually S<sup>1</sup> or a finite cyclic group for index theory calculations.  In particular, in Witten's original adaptation of index theory to loop spaces, we end up with positive energy representations of S<sup>1</sup> which become vector bundles over the original (finite dimensional) manifold with circle actions preserving the fibres.  One can decompose these according to the circle action whereupon one has a vector bundle for each k ∈ ℤ.  The positive energy criterion means that these are trivial below a certain integer and are always finite dimensional.  However, as there are an infinite number of them then the total dimension can be infinite dimensional.  Then the identity Λ<sub>-t</sub>V ⊗ S<sub>t</sub>V = ℂ has real meaning as the power of the t parameter indicates how the circle acts on that component of the vector bundle.  That is, if the circle action on V is the standard action then it is multiplication by t<sup>k</sup> on Λ<sup>k</sup> V and on S<sup>k</sup> V.

Comment: To tie it up with Ben's answer, the proof of this formula is through the Koszul complex of which Ben's resolution is a simple example.