# categorifying induction in homotopy type theory

Tags: categorification, type-theory, homotopy-theory, lo.logic, homotopy-type-theory

In trying to understand homotopy type theory, I stumbled upon the following silly question, which is likely to be trivial for the experts.

Let $B=\sqcup_{n\in\Bbb N} BS_n$, which I'd like to think of as the [categorified](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4841) version of the natural numbers $\Bbb N$. There is an obvious map $\sigma:B\to B$ that covers the successor map $s:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$, $s(n)=n+1$.

On the other hand, in Martin-Löf's type theory, there is the inductive type of natural numbers, written as

```
Inductive nat : Type := O : nat | S : nat -> nat.
```

in the syntax of Coq. The induction rule reads

```
nat_rect: forall P: nat -> Type,
x: PO -> ((forall n: nat, Pn -> P(Sn)) -> (forall n: nat, Pn)).
```

> Question: Can `nat` and `S` be interpreted as $B$ and $\sigma$? Presumably not, but why so?

In fact, such interpretation is impossible, according to Voevodsky: (1) because `nat` has contractible components (see `Theorem isasetnat` [here](https://raw.github.com/vladimirias/Foundations/master/Main_Library/Generalities/uu0.v)); (2) because `nat_rect` would cause the fibration $\sigma$ to have a section.

Both arguments elude me, however. (1) just needs better knowledge of Coq and more patience with this new way of writing down proofs than I've developed so far (so I don't follow the proof of his `Theorem isasetifdeceq`). In (2), I fail to see how `nat_rect` manages to mention a section of $\sigma$, or even that $\sigma$ must be a fibration. Indeed, let me parse the second line of the induction rule.

```
P: nat -> Type
```

I'm reading this as $p\in Map(B, U)$, where $U$ is a universe.

```
forall n: nat, Pn
```

This is the space of sections of $p^*\xi$, where $\xi$ is the universal fibration over $U$.

```
S: nat -> nat
```

This says $\sigma\in Map(B, B)$.

```
Pn -> P(Sn)
```

And this is $Map(\xi^{-1}(p(x)),\xi^{-1}(p(\sigma(x)))$.

```
forall n: nat, Pn -> P(Sn)
```

Here the previous space of maps needs to be understood as the homotopy fiber of a fibration
over $B$. This fibration is $G_\sigma^*(p\times p)^*Map(\xi,\xi)$, where $G_\sigma: B\to B\times B$ is the graph of $\sigma$, $p\times p: B\times B\to B\times B$, and $Map(\xi,\xi)$ is the fibration over $U\times U$ whose fiber over $(X,Y)$ is $Map(\xi^{-1}(X),\xi^{-1}(Y))$. (I understand that fibrations like $Map(\xi,\xi)$ and $\xi\times\xi$ are implicitly postulated by saying that $U$ is closed under products, dependent products, etc.; and these postulates correspond to Martin-Löf's universe formation rules.)

So we end up with the space of sections $Sect(G_\sigma^*(p\times p)^*Map(\xi,\xi))$.

```
(forall n: nat, Pn -> P(Sn)) -> (forall n: nat, Pn)
```

This is $Map(Sect(p^*\xi), Sect(G_\sigma^*(p\times p)^*Map(\xi,\xi)))$. Let me call it $M(p)$.

```
x: PO -> [(forall n: nat, Pn -> P(Sn)) -> (forall n: nat, Pn)]
```

and this is just $Map(\xi^{-1}(p(0)),M(p))$.

It seems to be a bit harder to parse the entire `nat_rect`; but I don't see how on earth this could help one to find a section of $\sigma$.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you wish to think of the sum of $BS_n$ as the categorified natural numbers. I am far more accustomed to seeing $BS_n$ as a categorified reciprocal whose decategorified shadow is $1/n!$, so that the sum of the $BS_n$ is a categorification of $e$, and the functor which takes a space $X$ to the space obtained as a sum of $E S_n \otimes_{S_n} X^n$ is a categorified exponential $\exp(X)$. 

Comment: Todd, then what is *your* categorified natural numbers? I'm simply following the well-trodden path a standard reference for which is Baez-Dolan. In more detail, some people tend to think of '$3$' as the 'equivalence class' of three apples, three pears, etc. Whereas $BS_n$ can be identified with the nerve of the category of $n$-element sets and their isomorphisms, and the universal $n$-fold covering $ES_n\to BS_n$ is the tautological covering over this nerve: the fiber over an object is the $n$-element set represented by this object.

Comment: Sergey, I didn't mean to seem aggressive here; I just wanted to understand your point of view. (I also acknowledge that there is more than one answer, depending on what one wants.) My first response is: $Fin$, the category of finite sets, which as a category with products that distribute over coproducts, decategorifies to the rig $\mathbb{N}$. But this suggests to me another way to interpret your meaning: just as $\mathbb{N}$ is the free commutative monoid on one generator, so the groupoid $\sum_n S_n$ is equivalent to the free symmetric monoidal category on one generator. No worries then.:-) 

Comment: What is the 'obvious' map $\sigma$? I guess it corresponds to a choice of inclusion $S_n \hookrightarrow S_{n+1}$ for each $n$. But I would wonder if there are any coherence conditions lying around. For example we know that $(0,s):1+\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is an isomorphism. I don't expect this be echoed in your $B$ above, but I feel there could be something lying around... (and I echo Todd's sentiment that categorification is an art, and so goes down various paths).

Comment: Todd and David, I agree, it should have been, *a* (not *the*) categorification (there are no articles in my native language, so I don't always get them right without a conscious effort). Also the category $Fin$ may be a better categorification of $\Bbb N$ than the nerve B of isomorphisms of $Fin$, so maybe I should've put 'categorification' in quotes. But in homotopy type theory, a 'categorification' (or '∞-categorification') of $\Bbb N$ should be a *type*, hopefully with additional structure corresponding to $+$, $∗$ and induction. Should it be sought in Awodey-style, not Voevodsky-style HTT?

Comment: David, in order to describe $\sigma$ more precisely let us think of $BS_n$ as the nerve of the category consisting of *one* $n$-element set $A_n$ and all bijections $A_n\to A_n$. Then $\sigma$ is determined by a choice of inclusions $A_0\subset A_1\subset\dots$. With *all* $n$-element sets, I guess indeed there has to be more than one $\sigma$, and the induction rule has to be rewritten so as to accommodate them all. In fact, this is interesting: will the modified `rect_nat` still have decidable equality?

Comment: @Sergey - you could consider the 'standard' totally ordered $n$-element sets $[n]$, and the inclusions $[n] \to [n+1]$ which miss the top element. This is nice and canonical. (PS no worries about 'a' vs 'the' - English is my native language and I sometimes forget when talking about higher categories: see http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+the :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first reason you give is sufficient to answer your question: any interpretation of `nat` (and any other type with decidable equality) must have contractible components. Let me try to unpack the proof:

The proof of `isasetifdeceq` goes as follows: Fixing $x:X$, we must show that $\text{Paths}(x,x)$ is contractible. We know that $\Sigma_{x':X}\text{Paths}(x,x')$ is contractible, so we just need the natural map $f:\text{Paths}(x,x)\to\Sigma_{x':X}\text{Paths}(x,x')$ to be a weak equivalence. This follows from the hypothesis using the theorem `onefiber`, which establishes that for a fibration which is empty over all but one path-component of the base, the total space is equivalent to a fiber over the remaining component.

Regarding (2). I think there's some confusion here: Let me try to unpack `nat_rect` in a more direct way: For any fibration $\Sigma_{\text{nat}} P\to\text{nat}$ over `nat`, given a point in $P_0$ and a section of $\Pi_{n:\text{nat}}\text{Map}(P_n,P_{n+1})\to\text{nat}$, you get a section of $P$. That is the interpretation of primitive recursion/induction.

Comment: Thanks, Ulrik! With your comments, I seem to understand the proof of `isasetifdeceq` now, but I'd say that semantically, it's an incredible kind of reasoning! The law of excluded middle, or 'decidable equality', is stated as saying that either there is a path between x and x' or there's no path between them; now the latter assertion also has another meaning: the path fibration, sending to x' every path from x to x' is empty over all components except that of x. Then the *topological* observations you mentioned apply. Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is the first time I see a topological ...


Comment: ... thinking have some application to logic, and not just providing an interpretation of what is already known in logic. It's a pity that 
there seems to be no more human-readable exposition of this argument.
I'll need to think it all over to see what is going on here (in particular in my example with $B$ and $\sigma$). 

Comment: Regarding (2), I certainly started from your 'unpacking', and I now regret that I didn't mention it in the first place, so as to improve presentation. But your unpacking is incomplete, as it still contains quantifiers and connectives ("for any fibration", "given a point", "AND a section"), which in particular conceals that these quantifiers are to be understood constructively. I just tried to do a more complete unpacking. In any case, do you agree that there is something wrong with argument (2)?

Comment: I agree it's an incredible kind of reasoning - that's part of the fun! And you're right that to give a full unpacking we have to interpret `Type` by a univalent universe, $U$, with corresponding fibration `$\Sigma_{A:U} T(A)\to U$` (universe a la Tarski with decoding $T$). And then `nat_rect` is represented by a section of a certain fibration with base space `$\text{Map}(\text{nat},U)$`. But it's frankly easier to understand in the type-theoretic notation, remembering to understand constructs constructively/continuously.

Comment: As for (2): The argument you refer to doesn't make much sense to me, since $\sigma$ is not interpreted as a fibration, so why does the question arise as to whether it has a section? That's why I suggested there might be some confusion going on – although I'm probably also confused :-)

Comment: That `nat_rect` causes $\sigma$ to have a section I've heard from Voevodsky himself, and I don't think I could misinterpret his words (I asked to clarify if he perhaps meant some fibration over `nat` but he insisted on $\sigma$). Perhaps this was just a wild guess on his part.