# What is categorification? (version 2.0)

Tags: ct.category-theory, categorification

A decade ago,  Gil Kalai  asked the question [What precisely Is "Categorification"?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4841/what-precisely-is-categorification)

After seeing some answers and some online pages, I think one of the meanings of categorification is the following:

It is not just that we want to associate a category for a set or a group or a manifold or a topological space. Along with assigning a category $F(A)$ with a set $A$, given a map of sets $A\rightarrow B$, we want to associate a functor $F(A)\rightarrow F(B)$. We want little more than this depending on the situation.

Consider a collection of objects that forms a category $\mathcal{C}$.

I think **a categorification of (elements of objects of) $\mathcal{C}$** is a functor $F:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \text{Cat}$, where $\text{Cat}$ is the category of all categories, such that the functor $F$ is an embedding.

Consider the collection of groups, the category formed by them is denoted by $\text{Grp}$. Then, a categorification is a functor $\text{Grp}\rightarrow \text{Cat}$ such that, this functor is an embedding of catgeories.

The objects of $\text{Grp}$ are not just sets but they come with two maps, namely $^{-1}:A\rightarrow A$ and $\cdot:A\times A\rightarrow A$. Then, categorification of $A$, should also come with (atleast) two functors $\cdot :F(A)\times F(A)\rightarrow F(A)$ and $^{-1}:F(A)\rightarrow  F(A)$. Any such functor, I would like to call a categorification of the category of groups.

Question : Is this notion of categorification compatible with the already existing notion of categorification? Is my understanding correct? In this sense, what could be an example of a categorification of category of topological spaces? Should $\text{Man}\rightarrow \text{Cat}$ defined as $M\rightarrow (M\rightrightarrows M)$ considered as categorification of manifolds? Should $\text{LieGrp}\rightarrow \text{Cat}$ defined as $G\mapsto (G\rightrightarrows *)$ considered as a categorification of Lie groups? What are the other possible categorifications in these examples?

Comment: It's impossible to answer because "categorification" is not something that is well-defined. None of the answers you linked have a paragraph that could be read as "Definition. Categorification is..." and such that everybody would agree that "yes, this is categorification, all known and future examples fall under this umbrella and nothing else". It's just a philosophy. Anyway, with your framework, I don't see how Khovanov homology could be seen as a categorification of the Jones polynomial?

Comment: I don't know what is a Jones Polynomial and what is Khovanov homology.. So, can not say anything about that... :) Yes, I agree that there is no agreement on what any catgeorification has to be... But, some notions of categorification is discussed in some places.. Is what I have said above compatible with existing notions of small classes of categorification that is already being discussed with some agreement

Comment: Categorification is the process of ‘upgrading’ objects from an $n$-categorical level to an $n+1$-categorical level — this means turning $0$-categorical objects defined in terms of sets into categories, or viewing certain types of categories and their morphisms as specific $2$-categories and morphisms between them, so on and so forth (in my opinion).

Comment: @AlecRhea Thanks for your comment :) The same sentence I heard more than once. As I heard this long back, which is also mentioned in the older question, I was expecting a clearer statement about categorification. please feel free to say If you wanted to say anything extra..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I was only offering my opinion, as I don’t think this question is amenable to a precise answer. I don’t see anything in the linked question about stepping beyond the ‘sets and functions to categories and functors’ level, as I’ve suggested with higher categorification, but perhaps that’s trivial.